# Expo router Link is not passing params to page 2

Tags: react-native, expo-router

Expo router Link is not passing params to page2, when I navigate to page2 from page1 on second time or more. However, during the first time navigation the params are passed correctly.

```
<Link href={{
       pathname: '/page2',
       params: {
          id: 10,
          name: "Test", 
         } 
      }}
>
   <Text>Go to page 2</Text>
</Link>

<Link href={{
       pathname: '/page1',
      }}
>
   <Text>Go to page 1</Text>
</Link>
```

---

output

First time navigating to page2

const {id, name} = useSearchParams()
returns id=10 and name="Test"

However, when navigating back to page 1 from page 2 and then navigating again to page 2,

const {id, name} = useSearchParams()
returns id=undefined and name=undefined

What is wrong with my code.